# C# call to PowerShell New-Session not returning result

Tags: c#, powershell, resultset

I am working on a console app using PowerShell to make remote calls to an Exchange Server. When scripted, it all works great. A snippet of the C# code is:

```
var cred = new PSCredential(exchangeUser, 
    GetSecureStringFromFile(@"c:\temp\mysecurestring.txt"));

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
    ps.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
    ps.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", exchangeUri);
    ps.AddParameter("Credential", cred);
    ps.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
    ps.AddParameter("AllowRedirection");
    var session = ps.Invoke();
    // at this point it appears theat the invoke worked,
    // however the session is a list of zero objects
}
```

When I call the `ps.Invoke()`, nothing appears to happen and I get a return variable that is an empty list.